# asp-for and if condition in same component

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

i'm trying to use a asp-for and a condition inside a component but i can't find a way to do that.

Here's my code

```
<label asp-for="@Model.Selected">
    @Model.Nome
    <input type="checkbox" asp-for="@Model.Selected"  />
</label>
```

and I wanna some like

```
<label asp-for="@Model.Selected">
    @Model.Nome
    <input type="checkbox" asp-for="@Model.Selected" @((Model.Unlucky) ? "disabled")  />
</label>
```

How can i do this in ASP.Net Razor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can add a new variable after that one and build the string to disable the input:

```
           @{
                var disabledTag = Model.Unlucky == null ? "disable" : "";
            }
            <input type="checkbox" asp-for="@Model.Selected" @disabledTag) />
```

Comment: For some reason Razor ignore all that comes after 'asp-for'. Look: https://i.imgur.com/ri2mbsw.png

Comment: `<input type="checkbox" asp-for="@Model.Selected" disabled="@Model.Unlucky" />` should be enough.

Comment: @jesse no, that will not work. HTML doesn't allow boolean values for boolean attributes

Comment: @DenisWasilew Have you tried it? I know it works. This is processed by razor, and results in either `disabled="disabled"` if property is true, or attribute is completely removed if property is false.

Answer (score 1):

Assumed that you're using Core MVC, you have two options to set `disabled` attribute conditionally inside `<input>` tag helper. Here are those options:

**Option 1 - Using HTML helper**

Create a static class which returns `HtmlString` to set `disabled` attribute with ternary operator:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlContent SetDisabled(this IHtmlHelper helper, bool value)
    {
        return new HtmlString(value ? @"disabled=""disabled""" : "");
    }
}
```

And then use that helper inside Razor view:

```
<input type="checkbox" asp-for="@Model.Selected" @Html.SetDisabled(Model.Unlucky) />
```

**Option 2 - Create Tag Helper Attribute**

You can build a custom class derived from `TagHelper` instance and specify target element to add `disabled` attribute:

```
[HtmlTargetElement("checkbox")]
public class DisabledCheckBox : TagHelper
{
    [HtmlAttributeName("asp-disabled")]
    public bool IsDisabled { get; set; }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        if (IsDisabled)
        {
            var d = new TagHelperAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
            output.Attributes.Add(d);
        }
        base.Process(context, output);
    }
}
```

Then you could use that attribute inside tag helper:

```
<input type="checkbox" asp-for="@Model.Selected" asp-disabled="@Model.Unlucky" />
```

**Notes:**

1) For both options, make sure that you've tag helper support enabled inside `_ViewImports.cshtml`, by checking existence of these lines below:

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers 
@addTagHelper *, YourProjectNamespace
```

2) `disabled` attribute is a boolean attribute which when exist, it disabled the input element no matter what value it has. Therefore, `disabled` attribute must be absent if you want to keep it enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You need a ternary operator. You can use it like this. Assuming `Model.Unluck` is a string, otherwise you need to use `ToString()` on it because both results must be of the same datatype.

```
<input type="checkbox" asp-for="@(Model.Selected ? Model.Unluck : "disabled")"  />
```

If `Model.Unluck` is the boolean for the operator, then you do this.

```
<input type="checkbox" asp-for="@(Model.Unluck ? "enabled" : "disabled")"  />
<input type="checkbox" asp-for="@(Model.Unluck ? "true" : "false")"  />
```

Comment: Model.Unluck is a Boolean, when its True I wanna that checkbox is disabled. But when element has a "asp-for" the result is not that i expected, its ignore the if condition

Comment: Right.. But
My problem is: I can't do that condition and at the same time this "asp-for="@Model.Selected" "

Because this: " asp-for="@Model.Selected" " will verify if checkbox will check ou not and this: "@(Model.Selected ? Model.Unluck : "disabled")" will verify if checkbox is disable or not

Maybe I'm trying for the hard way, and the solution for my problem is not what I'm searching XD

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any ternary operations or custom tag helpers to make element disabled in razor.

You can just use:

`<input disabled="@Model.Unlucky" />`

It will render `<input disabled="disabled" />` if `Model.Unlucky` is `true`, and will omit `disabled` attribute completely if `Model.Unlucky` is `false`.

It also can be used with `readonly` or any other attributes where you need such behavior.

The trick here is that attribute value should have boolean type to be interpreted this way. For example if `@Model.Unlucky` is a string `"true"`, it will just render as is `disabled="true"`.